# search and replace a pattern in a line in perl

Tags: perl

I need a help with regular expression:

I have a file which has a line like this:

```
label   9   { V { some_text ; } W { some_text;} } #12345.
```

now the condition is, if the line has label 9, I have to replace it with NOP (everything else on the line should remain the same) and I can't seem to figure out why

This is what I did (only releveant portion of the code):

```
my $cur_line = $_;


if($cur_line =~ s/label\s+9/)

{

       $cur_line =~ s/label\s+9/NOP/;
       print "$cur_line";

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're confusing the substitution operator [`s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) with the matching operator [`m//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html).  toolic's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Your code did not compile for me untill I changed:

```
if($cur_line =~ s/label\s+9/)
```

to:

```
if($cur_line =~ /label\s+9/)
```

Note the `s/`.  Then, it performed the substitution you desire.

You can simplify this as:

```
my $cur_line = $_;
if ($cur_line =~ s/label\s+9/NOP/) {
    print $cur_line;
}
```

Comment: or even `print if s/label\s+9/NOP/;`